# Can I use the default UIViewController for a SCNScene for 3D game or why does the Xcode default come with a UIViewController instead

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

Hey I am trying to make a 3D game using Scenekit but I'm confused as to weather I can use the default class GameViewController: UIViewController or do I need to use a SCNScene instead.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import AudioToolbox
import QuartzCore
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit
import StoreKit
import GameKit
import iAd

class PlayController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, SKSceneDelegate, SCNSceneRendererDelegate{


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

Comment: I completely sympathise with your frustration. The template not following the conventions and paradigms of Scene Kit as described in the documentation/reference is ridiculous.

Comment: could you please elaborate on what confuses you?

Comment: Well i can get the 3D scene to appear and everything fine but I'm just thinking for a sprite kit game you use a class PlayController: SKScene. but for scene kit it seems that you use a UIViewController and the eventual change it to a SCNcene with this code let scnView = self.view as! SCNView is this the right or best way?

Comment: Abstract all of the protocols into a class for managing the game state.

Comment: honestly I have know idea what that means haha